# Is variable framerate still distracting with G-sync/Freesync?

Tags: monitor, framerate

I understand what G-sync/Freesync does and that variable framerate should feel smoother with it, but do you still notice it when **framerate is fluctuating** from let's say **60-90 FPS, or 90-120 FPS**, ...and more importantly - **is it distracting**? Does locking framerate to some flat amount provide better experience in terms of not noticing spikes/slowdowns in framerate?

Comment: That would depend on the individual, I guess. In my case, I own a 30-60 FPS G-Sync screen and only notice the fluctuation when my framerate drops below 30 FPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main purpose of GSync/Freesync is precisely to prevent you from noticing such fluctuations (which you usually notice by sudden lag spikes). In addition adaptive sync prevents screen tearing from framerates higher than native refresh rates of the monitor.

Within the adapative sync enabled area (usually 30Hz+) the tech is active and you won't be able to notice even sudden frame drops.